# How to format Visual Studio Code's underscore

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to the programming community as I just started my work just recently.

The problem that I'm having is that my underscore looks like this "__" and not like this "_ _". I wanted to see the space between the underscores. I was fiddling with VS code settings while googling for about 3 hours, and I have yet to arrive at an answer to fix my problem.

Thank you

Comment: choose a different font

Answer (score 3):

There's a configuration on VS code called "letterSpacing".

Just go to preferences and search.

If you increase the letter spacing, then the underscores will look like what you want.

Comment: My underscores in the terminal were invisible (looked like spaces). I changed the terminal letter spacing to 1 and back to 0 and that fixed it.